# If $\mathfrak{c} = 2^\mathbb{N}$ why $|D^\mathfrak{c}|=\mathfrak{c}$ with $D = \{0, 1\}$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, topological-groups

Let $\mathfrak{c} = 2^\mathbb{N}$ and $D^\mathfrak{c}$ be the topological product of $\mathfrak{c}$ copies
of the discrete Abelian group $D = \{0, 1\}$. If $D^\mathfrak{c}$ taken as a group is denoted by $G$,
and $D^\mathfrak{c}$ taken as a topological space is denoted by $X$.

Why $|G| = |X| = c$?

I think maybe it has to do with Boolean but I'm not sure.

On the other hand I am correct or I am wrong that $|G| = |D^\mathfrak{c}|=|D|^\mathfrak{c} =2^\mathfrak{c}> \mathfrak{c}$?

I am studying this example of Korovin Orbits in the book Topological groups and related structures of Mikhail Tkachenko.

[image]

Thank you for your Help!

Comment: $|D^\mathfrak{c}|=\mathfrak{c}$ is incorrect, as you observe this cardinality is $2^\mathfrak{c}$ (pretty much by definition)

Comment: Why do you think $\vert D^\mathfrak{c}\vert=\mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I am studying A example of Korovin Orbits in the book Topological groups and related structures of Mikhail Tkachenko. (
I UPLOAD THE IMAGE TO MY PUBLICATION)

Comment: @LuisPrado ... Wow. What the heck?

Comment: @NoahSchweber $2^{\omega}$ looks like ordinal exponentiation, doesn't it? But then it's weird to use it as a cardinal. _looks confused_

Comment: @DanielFischer Annoyingly, "$2^{\omega_\alpha}$" is generally used for "$2^{\aleph_\alpha}$" (and in particular "$2^\omega$" generally refers to $\mathfrak{c}$). The reason is at least partially that the ordinal exponentiation version would be silly (namely, it would just be $\omega_\alpha$ again). I don't see any way to interpret the quoted passage as correct; it just seems bonkers.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Colour me surprised. If I could, I'd upvote the first word of your comment a thousand times. Annoying indeed.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm a huge fan personally of using "$^\kappa\lambda$" to denote cardinal exponentiation (since it looks like going from $\kappa$ to $\lambda$) but nobody does that anymore. :( Similarly I'd love to use different symbols for ordinal vs. cardinal addition and multiplication. It's such a stupid roadblock for students, especially given that we then ignore the usual context clues!

Answer (score -1):

It is the case that $|D^{\mathfrak{c}}|=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. We can find a bijection from the product of $\mathfrak{c}$ copies of $D$, which you have written $D^{\mathfrak{c}} $, to the power set $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ of $\mathfrak{c}$ as follows.

If $x\in D^{\mathfrak{c}} $, then $x$ essentially consists of a mapping from each element of $\mathfrak{c}$ to either $0$ or $1$, and we may write $x(c)$ to denote the value ($0$ or $1$) corresponding to $c\in\mathfrak{c}$. Let $S(x)$ be the set of all elements $c\in \mathfrak{c}$ for which $x(c)=1$. Then $S: D^{\mathfrak{c}} \mapsto 2^{\mathfrak{c}}$ is a bijection. In essence, $x$ acts as an “indicator function” for every subset of $\mathfrak{c}$ indicating (with a $1$) which elements of $\mathfrak{c}$ the subset contains.